# Assertion in conditional regex

Tags: regex

Having following regex:

```
(?(?<=\AA)a|e)/g
```

and test string:

```
Aa
Ae
Be
```

it matches `a`(line #1), `e`(line #2), `e`(line #3). 
I think it should match just `a`(line #1) because there are 3 lines but only ONE string - `\AA` matches `A` only once (on the first line of the string) and therefore applies `a` pattern which matches only `a` in the fist line.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ with pcre(php) flavor

Comment: Remove the `g` flag.

Comment: "and therefore applies `a` pattern which matches only a in the fist line" - you've a **conditional** expression,  it tries to match `e` in case the condition (`\AA`) is not matched. Giving three results is correct.

Comment: I don't think getting 3 results is correct. As I wrote there is only one string so it's only one match with the case ˋ\AAˋ is matched.

Comment: Could You please try to answer my last post?

Answer (score -1):

> Should't it match just `a` (line #1) only?

### No.

Your current expression translated to English:

- `?(?<=\AA)` - if current character is preceded by beginning of string AND A

  - then match `a` - this will match `a` in first line
  - else (= any other cases) match `e` - this will match `e` in lines 2 and 3

Comment: So is there one string or 3(one per each line)?

Comment: Sorry but it can't be 3 strings. If it was it wouldn’t mach the `e` in line #2 (if the first character is `A` then try to mach `a` - and it fails because the line is `Ae`, so `a` doesn't mach `e`)

Comment: Ok,  now I understand what doe you mean. Maybe update your question and give a bit more details about your tests.

Comment: I've updated my question. Can You now try to answer it?